# PHP: what's better practice, foreach or hustle with array functions?

Tags: php, arrays

Between the following two code snippets which one is considered better? This loop will run a few dozen times itself and each times it will loop 20 times, tops, more often just 2-3.

```
foreach (glob("$directory/*.yml") as $filename) {
    $files[$filename] = $provider;
}
```

or

```
$filenames = glob("$directory/*.yml");
$files = array_combine($filenames, array_fill(0, count($filenames), $provider));
```

Comment: If you use `foreach` for significant amount(_i.e something about 150000_) of array then its always better then all those `array functions` else simply use array functions

Comment: Can you make the question less subjective by changing the word "better" for something else? Like "more performant" or "more concise and allows future expansion"? As it stands, answers can only be pure opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is much clearer and does not generate and then instantly discard an extra array. But the key thing is it's simpler and easier to understand - when this code is revisited later, the reader will immediately know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

For better practice to know php in depth, I'd suggest that you stick with `array_combine`or that `array_fill` functions of yours.
However, in my opinion, your first method is much simpler and readable than the second one.

Besides, in real life application you might encounter some issue if you use your second method like php version doesn't support that function whatsoever.

And please be aware if `$filenames` is a null or even an empty array, that `array_combine` of yours will throw a warning. As of PHP 5.3.2, `array_combine(array(), array())` throws a warning and returning FALSE, instead of returning `array()`.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34857

As for `array_fill`, it'd work best for your scenario. If you happen to change to any scenario where you use `array_fill` on class objects, It'd mess everything up.

Comment: The empty `array_combine()` problem fix was released in PHP 5.4.0, see https://3v4l.org/HTncu . PHP 5.4 itself is end-of-life now and no longer supported. This is not a problem on any PHP version you should be running.